# Putting oneself in doubt, when it comes to a Mitzvah Derabanan

Tags: halacha, shema, derabanan, safek, time-bound

The Mishnah Berurah (46 S”K 31) brings an opinion - which is how the SA Harav rules - that in a case where one is afraid that he might miss the time of Shema by the time the Tzibur reaches the place where Shema is recited, that he is not obligated to recite more than the first paragraph of Shema - which is biblical - before Davening, and not the rest, which is Derabanan.

The question is: is it always true that one can push off a Mitzvah Derabanan, even in a case where the only way he will be able to fulfill it in the best way, is by waiting long enough for there to be a doubt as to whether he will still be able to fulfill the Mitzvah? Is it because of the rule ספיקא דרבנן לקולא - if not, then what is the reason for this?

Comment: Why would he be unable? He may not have to but why would he be unable?

Comment: I don't understand the example. If the time is coming up then he can say the required paragraphs as he is required to.

Comment: I'd like to see that SA Harav. I can tell you for a fact that Lubavitchers (who obviously follow SA Harav) regularly daven at minyanim where the tzibbur will not reach shema in time, and they say all three paragraphs. Nobody suffices with saying just the first one.

Comment: Miss the time of *shema* according to everyone?